# App distribution as Team Member

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I am a iOS developer and I created app for my client. So he created organization and added me as Team member. Now he want me to send him a build so he can put it in App Store, but I don't know if its possible without team admin role, because I have "Your account does not have permission to create IOS Distibution certificates" error when I want to save for AD-hoc deployment.

Are there any other ways to archive this beside:
- Give him code so he logs onto his agent account and builds and archive app by himself?
- Ask him to give me his account and then I archive app and send him?

Answer (score 0):

He can create the distribution certificate and you can use it.

Comment: So he creates distribution certificate and then send me private key?

Comment: That's what I've done in the past in this situation. He can export his distribution certificate and send it to you (telling you the temporary password). I think he can also create the distribution certificate _and the profile_ and you can download the profile. It's been a while since I did this, but that's my memory of how this goes. Certainly I was able to build, ad hoc export, and provide an archive for sending to the app store, without ever sharing the code.